# List of all creation times for subfolders and specific files

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have 100 folders and inside each folder I have one specific file. I would like to extract all creation dates from the 100 folders, and also extract all creation dates from these specific files that are inside each folder.

I cannot figure out how to get these attributes using `dir` from command line using Windows 10?

Comment: Thank you, I really apreciatte your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the PowerShell [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) cmdlet with specific variations of  `-Filter`, `-File`, `-Recurse` and  `-Directory` parameters to create variable objects of the file names and subfolders. Afterwards, [loop](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) over the file and directory variables and create a couple [array](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html) object variables.

With this you can create a couple lists with the *creation date and time* of the specific files, and the *creation date and time* of the specific sub-folders, giving you the desired output as described.

---

### PowerShell Script

> **Note:** *Set the `$fName` variable value to be that of the specific file name you need to search for with or without wildcards in the file
>   name e.g. `FileName123.png`, `*File*.txt`, etc. Also set the `$src`
>   variable value to be the full path to the parent folder which the
>   first sub-folder is within containing the specific files you need to
>   get the attributes values.*

```
$fName   = "FileName123.png";
$src     = "C:\Users\Test\Folder\";
$csvFile = "C:\Folder\csvexport\test.csv";

$F = (Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter $fName -File -Recurse);
$D = (Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Directory -Recurse);

$Files = ($F | %{"$($_.CreationTime),$($_.FullName)"});
$Dirs  = ($D | %{"$($_.CreationTime),$($_.FullName)"});

$Files | Out-File $csvFile -Append;
$Dirs  | Out-File $csvFile -Append;
```

**Output Example**

```
09/01/2019 20:30:28,C:\Users\Test\Folder\Dir1\FileName123.png
09/01/2019 20:31:02,C:\Users\Test\Folder\Dir2\FileName123.png
09/01/2019 20:31:05,C:\Users\Test\Folder\Dir3\FileName123.png
09/01/2019 20:30:39,C:\Users\Test\Folder\Dir1
09/01/2019 20:30:45,C:\Users\Test\Folder\Dir2
09/01/2019 20:30:49,C:\Users\Test\Folder\Dir3
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [5 Ways to Open Windows PowerShell in Windows 10](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/5-ways-to-open-windows-powershell-in-windows-10.html)
- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [Out-File](https://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html)